# Como puedo hacer un sticky footer me siga cuando

Tags: html, css, web

esa es la pregunta como podria crear/hacer un footer que cuando baje por la página o suba este se mantenga y me siga¿ Muchas gracias. Esto es solo una prueba pero aqui más o menos he conseguido que el footer sobresalga y de manera que subes o bajes te siga, pero me sobresale de la pantalla y el div no me hace el 100% no se como hacerlo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <style>
        body{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }

        footer{
            position: -webkit-sticky;
            position: sticky;
            align-self: flex-end;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            padding: 50px;
            font-size: 20px;
            /* align-self: flex-end; */
            background-color:black;
            line-height: 3;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
        }

        footer p{
            color: white;
        }

        .caja{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="caja">
        ¿Qué es Lorem Ipsum?
         Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y 
      archivos 
      de texto.um, nerísticas del lenguaje, etc.de Len su forma original 
      exacta, acompañadas por versiones en Inglés de la traducción 
      realizada en 1914 por H. Rackham.
    </div>
    <footer>
        <p>ESTO ES EL FOOTER</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que has intentado?, precisamente un posicionamiento sticky te ayuda con eso

Comment: Ya esta editado, he añadido el código de como lo teniaa

Comment: Hola, prueba editar lo siguiente en los estilos del `footer`: Quita el `top:0` y cambia la posición a `position:fixed`. Para mas informacion de las posiciones, te recomiendo leer [position - CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: lo hace, pero el texto final de la caja no se acaba viendo

Answer (score 0):

He cambiado la clase `width` por `max-width` de `.footer` y la he mantenido en 100%.

Acá está el código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <style>
        body{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }

        footer{
            position: -webkit-sticky;
            position: sticky;
            align-self: flex-end;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            padding: 50px;
            font-size: 20px;
            /* align-self: flex-end; */
            background-color:black;
            line-height: 3;
            text-align: center;
            max-width: 100%;
        }

        footer p{
            color: white;
        }

        .caja{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="caja">
        ¿Qué es Lorem Ipsum?
         Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y 
      archivos 
      de texto.um, nerísticas del lenguaje, etc.de Len su forma original 
      exacta, acompañadas por versiones en Inglés de la traducción 
      realizada en 1914 por H. Rackham.
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo fugiat maiores, molestias quod corporis earum ullam iure et officia facilis assumenda ex, dolorum voluptatum qui dolor perspiciatis rerum quisquam deleniti.
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In eligendi laborum, asperiores ipsam nobis consequatur, quasi alias expedita! Beatae vero, eum ex illum laudantium nostrum vitae atque tenetur sed asperiores?
      <br><br><br><br><br>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In eligendi laborum, asperiores ipsam nobis consequatur, quasi alias expedita! Beatae vero, eum ex illum laudantium nostrum vitae atque tenetur sed asperiores?
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In eligendi laborum, asperiores ipsam nobis consequatur, quasi alias expedita! Beatae vero, eum ex illum laudantium nostrum vitae atque tenetur sed asperiores?
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In eligendi laborum, asperiores ipsam nobis consequatur, quasi alias expedita! Beatae vero, eum ex illum laudantium nostrum vitae atque tenetur sed asperiores?
    </div>
    <footer>
        <p>ESTO ES EL FOOTER</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

También agregué un par de líneas adicionales de `lorem` para que se note que el footer "te sigue" y no se deforma.

Espero mi solución te sirva.